# Filter product by different tables - Cakephp 3.8

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends,
I appreciate if anyone can help me.

I created a field to filter products by brand, state and city after entering a keyword. When I have the search input and the brand field works well. However, when I add more fields, such as state and city he does not seek.

ProductsTable.php

```
.
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
       'foreignKey' => 'user',
       'joinType' => 'INNER',
]);
.
```

UsersTable.php

```
$this->hasMany('Products', [
       'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
]);
```

Finally, I do the method to filter like this:

```
public function search()
    {           
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('search');

        $product = $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Brands', 'Users'],
            'conditions' => ['and' => [
                'Products.name like' => '%'. $this->request->getQuery('search') . '%',
                'Brands.id like' => '%'.$this->request->getQuery('brand').'%',
                'Users.state like' => '%'.$this->request->getQuery('estate').'%',
                'Users.city like' => '%'.$this->request->getQuery('city').'%',
            ]
        ],
            'order' => ['Products.price' => 'ASC' ]
        ];
        
        $this->set('products', $this->paginate($this->Products));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['products', 'brands', 'users']);

    }
```

The method does not give error, but it filters as I said earlier.

I appreciate if anyone can analyze.

Comment: If you're already in the Products controller, then "Products.Users" is redundant, and you probably just need to use "Users" in all those places.

Comment: P.S. Your containment says "Produtcs.User", not "Products.User". Again, probably not the cause of any issue here, but it's not going to help...

Comment: You haven't shown us anything at all about the form that this is coming from, so we have no idea what might be causing that. It's maybe best done as a separate question, once you have this one done.

Comment: It's ok. Regarding the method, when you add more filters it doesn't work. Only when the brands field is triggered. When I fill in state and city it does not display any product, but having to do with the search.